# Kotlin mutableMap foreach

Tags: kotlin

My question is more to understand the documentation. It say's:

```
fun <K, V> Map<out K, V>.forEach(
action: (Entry<K, V>) -> Unit)
```

However I don't understand how to implement it. How I get the Key and Value inside the loop?

I want to sum for each item in `listItems` the value of the price. The map associates a string with an item

```
data class Item(val name: String, val description: String, val price: String, val index: Int)
```

Imagine `listItems` contains this:

> listItems["shirt"]-> name: shirt, description: lorem ipsum, price: 10, index: 0
>
> listItems["shoes"]-> name: shoes, description: lorem ipsum, price: 30, index: 0

So the code would be something like:

```
var total: Int = 0
listItems.forEach {
       total += parseInt(value.price)
    }
```

However I don't understand how to acces this `value` refering to the `V` of the documentation

Answer (score 21):

The lambda that you pass to `forEach { ... }` accepts an `Entry<K, V>`, and you can work with this entry, accessing its `value`:

```
listItems.forEach { total += parseInt(it.value.price) }
```

Which is equivalent to this using [explicit lambda parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax):

```
listItems.forEach { entry -> total += parseInt(entry.value.price) }
```

Or, since Kotlin 1.1, you can use [destructuring in lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html#destructuring-in-lambdas):

```
listItems.forEach { (_, value) -> total += parseInt(value.price) }
```

---

If you only need to sum the values, you can use [`sumBy { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-by.html):

```
val total = listItems.entries.sumBy { parseInt(it.value.price) }
```

Comment: I finally reached the "explicit lanbda paramater" solution by myself but the sumby is a nice and better solution, thanks!

Comment: Since 1.1 you can also do `it.value.price.toInt()`

Answer (score 4):

For the some of a collection, instead of using `forEach`, I'd suggest going for `sumBy` or `fold`.

You can get the underlying values by calling `value` on the `Map<K,V>`.
So to get the `sum` you'd do something like this:

```
val total = listItems.values.sumBy{ it.price.toInt() }
```

Now there's no need to introduce a mutable `var`.